# How to display information in a div outside the map?

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I created a simple map with two polygons (most of the code I got from the [Interactive Choropleth Map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) tutorial). I added a `L.control()` to show information about the polygons in a div. Contrary to the tutorial, I would like to have this div displayed outside the map.

To get a clue what I mean please look here: jsfiddle.net/Tbr9p/

I'm pretty new to `leaflet` and `javascript` so it would be nice if anybody can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Leaflet is styling the `_div` you return on the event handler so it appears as a popup. Just get the DIV you want to write into (by ID, not by Class) and edit it.

See jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7n58L/6/

lines 103 and 110 of the JS, as well as some CSS and HTML tweaks. I think I changed some names.

Answer (score 0):

see updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tbr9p/9/)

```
document.getElementById("information").innerText = layer.feature.properties.Name;
```